# Optimizing a query using derived tables

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

As part of a daily cron job, I need to run a query that processes a whole lot of data. This data is related to the visitors coming to a website, and updating the data with what we have captured previously.

The query relies on 2 derived tables (select queries in the `FROM` section), to do its work —

```
SELECT  
  new_visits.visitor_id, new_visits.visit_id, new_visits.visit_first_action_time,
  new_visits.purchased as purchased,  
  ifnull(existing_visitors.purchased, 0) as existing_purchased 
FROM   

    ( SELECT          
        tv.visitor_id, tv.visit_id, tv.visit_first_action_time, 
        if(tc.idgoal=0,1,0) as purchased                       
      FROM 
        tbl_log_visit tv left outer join tbl_log_conversion tc         
      ON 
        tv.visit_id = tc.visit_id AND tc.idgoal = 0                       
      WHERE
        tv.idsite= 12 AND tv.visit_id >= 477256              
      ORDER BY tv.visit_id       
      LIMIT 1000 ) new_visits

   LEFT JOIN          

   ( SELECT 
       visitor_id, max(visit_seq) as visit_seq, purchased 
     FROM 
       tbl_last_input_visit where site_id = 12 
     GROUP BY visitor_id, purchased ) existing_visitors      

   ON new_visits.visitor_id = existing_visitors.visitor_id 

ORDER BY new_visits.visitor_id, new_visits.visit_id;
```

With smaller datasets, this query works just fine. However, as the data increases, the slowly becomes progressively slower. Until a point where it starts to take around 30 seconds to executed (at the start it takes around 1.5 seconds).

The query plan is as follows —

```
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                  | type  | possible_keys                                                                     | key           | key_len | ref               | rows    | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>             | ALL   | NULL                                                                              | NULL          | NULL    | NULL              |    1000 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>             | ALL   | NULL                                                                              | NULL          | NULL    | NULL              |  705325 |                                 |
|  3 | DERIVED     | tbl_input_visit        | ref   | visitorid_seq,visitorid_idx                                                       | idvisitor_seq | 4       |                   |  490047 | Using where                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tv                     | range | PRIMARY,index_idsite_config_datetime,index_idsite_datetime,index_idsite_idvisitor | PRIMARY       | 4       | NULL              | 4781309 | Using where                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tc                     | ref   | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY       | 8       | tv.idvisit        |       1 | Using index                     |
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
```

At this point, one option I have explored is creation of temporary tables. However, the overhead of doing so is quite significant. 
I also realise that since this query relies on derived tables, MySQL will not be able to reuse any underlying indexes.

Here are the create statements for the tables involved —

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_last_input_visit` (
  `site_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `visitor_id` binary(8) NOT NULL,
  `visit_seq` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `purchase_cycle_seq` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `visit_in_cycle_seq` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `purchased` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'l_ij',
  UNIQUE KEY `idvisitor_seq` (`site_id`,`visitor_id`,`visit_seq`),
  KEY `idvisitor_idx` (`site_id`,`visitor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `tbl_log_visit` (
  `visit_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idsite` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `visitor_id` binary(8) NOT NULL,
  `visit_last_action_time` DATETIME,
  `config_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`visit_id`),
  KEY `index_idsite_config_datetime` (`site_id`,`config_id`,`visit_last_action_time`),
  KEY `index_idsite_datetime` (`site_id`,`visit_last_action_time`),
  KEY `index_idsite_idvisitor` (`site_id`,`visitor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `tbl_log_conversion` (
  `visit_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `visitor_id` binary(8) NOT NULL,
  `idgoal` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `idorder` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`visit_id`,`idgoal`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_idsite_idorder` (`site_id`,`idorder`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Is there some way I can go about improving the performance of this query?